# how to make multiple field unique key with group in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, key, unique

i want to make unique key with group at that time i am using mongodb database and i insert data using json file my json file data is like the following:

```
{
   'name' : 'abc',
   'mobileno': '2301658146',
   'provider': 'Airtel'
}
{
   'name' : 'abc',
   'mobileno': '2301658146',
   'provider': 'docomo'
}
```

If mobileno and provider match an existing record, overwrite the existing record, otherwise insert a new record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) which will do what you want:

```
db.mobile.update({ '_id':{'mobileno': '2301658146', 'provider': 'Airtel'}}, {'name' : 'abc'}, {upsert:true})
db.mobile.update({ '_id':{'mobileno': '2301658146', 'provider': 'docomo'}}, {'name' : 'abc'}, {upsert:true})
```

**Result**:

```
{ "_id" : { "mobileno" : "2301658146", "provider" : "Airtel" }, "name" : "abc" }
{ "_id" : { "mobileno" : "2301658146", "provider" : "docomo" }, "name" : "abc" }
```

Running the same command again with the same `_id.mobileno` and `_id.provider` will update the existing document:

```
db.mobile.update({ '_id':{'mobileno': '2301658146', 'provider': 'Airtel'}}, {'name' : 'xyz'}, {upsert:true})
```

**Result**:

```
{ "_id" : { "mobileno" : "2301658146", "provider" : "Airtel" }, "name" : "xyz" }
{ "_id" : { "mobileno" : "2301658146", "provider" : "docomo" }, "name" : "abc" }
```